# How to read in attribute value from json given in attribute name

Tags: java, json

I am attempting to read in the following json using the jackson java library:

```
"WeirdData": {
  "07f072ea-80c9-4fac-8235-2e1e6576ce2e": "crapapple"
},
```

How should the model look like to be able to be able to read above json into a class, can this even be done?

```
class SponsorEntityIdsData {
  @JsonProperty("GUID")
  var id: String? = null
  var name: String? = null
}
```

Comment: This is not a valid JSON, is your example part of larger JSON object?

Comment: This is data I am getting from an api endpoint. I suspected that this data would not be valid, I'll try and convince the api owner to fix this. yes, this is part of major blob of data.

Comment: I don't believe that Jackson can handle invalid JSON input

Comment: What do you mean by `this is part of major blob of data`? Did you cut the example off of the complete JSON content? If so, we'd need a minimal, yet _complete_ example of said blob/JSON.

Comment: Yes, since it didn't appear to be relevant, the json looked "normal" and I was trying to simplify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use HashMap Collection in your java pojo class.
You will get id (key) by using `WeirdData.keySet()` and 
by using key you will get name.

```
class WeirdData {
 HashMap<String,String> WeirdData;
}
```